# DQL returns 0 expected result where MySQL has 2

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a doctrine query (DQL) on my user repository which returns 0 results when I use a like :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');
$qb->select('q.id, q.roles');
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('q.roles', ':role1'));
$qb->setParameter('role1', '"%ROLE_ADMIN%"');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

whereas if I manually execute the query on MySQL, I have 2 results

```
SELECT * FROM user u WHERE u.roles LIKE "%ROLE_ADMIN%"
```

I have 2 users have "ROLE_ADMIN"

I do not understand

I cleared the cache

I tried to make a query that returns all the users, and it works, the 2 ROLE_ADMIN are in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the double qoutes inside `::setParameter()` call, as they would be interpreted as a part of searched expression. Use only one pair of quotes.

```
$qb->setParameter('role1', '%ROLE_ADMIN%');
```